# Display year value before a set of posts

Tags: custom-post-types, query, date

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a page template which displays "case studies" where "case studies" is a custom post type.
the page template called: **page-case-studies.php**

I actually use very simple custom query with pagination. here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="heading"><h3 class="normalh3">2015’s Case Studies</h3></div>


        <?php
        // WP_Query arguments
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array (
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'paged' => $paged, 
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_type' => 'case-study'
        );

        // The Query
        $query_case_studies = new WP_Query( $args );

        // The Loop
        if ( $query_case_studies->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query_case_studies->have_posts() ) {
        $query_case_studies->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="two-col">
            <div class="col2 first" >
                <div class="text">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php $aa=get_the_excerpt();
                    echo substr($aa, 0, 245);?>...</p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="btn">
                        More on how we won together &nbsp;<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/button-arrow.png"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <div class="image">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">

                        <?php
        // Must be inside a loop.

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        else {
            echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/images/placeholder1.jpg" />';
        }
            ?>
            </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!--<two-col>-->
        <?php }
            } else {
            // no posts found
            }
            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();
          ?>

    </div>
```

Notice this line at the top:

```
<div class="heading"><h3 class="normalh3">2015’s Case Studies</h3></div>
```

I wanted to display the year related to a list of the post types. meaning that on 2016 I would like to display "Case Studies from 2016" and continue the list of the "case Studies"

Right now it is static and not working. it's not even inside the loop so in 2016 nothing will happen except the continuation of the list of all case studies.

Anyway I can add heading **H3** for example inside the list displaying the current year?
would appreciate help here
thanks

Comment: Simply compare the year in the post date of the current post with the previous one and according to that, display the year

Comment: Do u have an example of how to echo out the year in the post date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the year value between the current post and the previous post and based on that display your h3 tag with your year-based content

I'm not going to reproduce your code, only the important parts. Note that I may need to strip some tags in order to add my section of code

```
if ( $query_case_studies->have_posts() ) {
    // Define the variable to hold the year value from the post date
    $date_variable = '';

    while ( $query_case_studies->have_posts() ) {
    $query_case_studies->the_post(); 

        // Get the post date, but only the year part
        $year = get_the_date( 'Y' );

        // Now lets compare $year with $date_variable and display the year accordingly
        if ( $date_variable != $year ) // Year values are not the same
            echo '<div class="heading"><h3 class="normalh3">' . $year . '@apos; Case Studies</h3></div>';

        // Set $date_variable to $year
        $date_variable = $year;

        // Rest of what you need to do
```

Comment: Seems like it works great. I will be smarter in 2016 to check if the year changes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hahaha, no problem. It should work when the clock hits 2016. Enjoy ;-)